# Does TI Tiva C ADC 5V tolerant?

Tags: adc, texas-instruments

Does TI Tiva C uC ADC input is 5V tolerant ?

EDIT:

Found ADC parameters in datasheet http://cl.ly/image/3D1Q3q09470J. Please don't down vote.

Thanks

Comment: What does the data sheet say?

Comment: Thanks. http://cl.ly/image/3D1Q3q09470J << I'm not sure, but maximum ADC input is Vdda. And Vdda is 3.63V. So I think Tiva ADC is not 5V tolerant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at the table called "Absolute Maximum Ratings" if you want to know if the chip will *tolerate* 5 volts (as opposed to *function properly*) on the analog inputs. It looks like some pins (at least when used as GPIOs) can tolerate up to 5.5 volts while others are limited to 0.3 volts above Vdd.